# SSRS Query for Test Case outcome

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-2015

I currently connect to TFS 2015 with Excel and connect to the analysis server.
I have created a Pivot table that is setup to display the reults of Test Suites, I can filter it by Projects and area paths in the pivot table.
I then open another worksheet and use vlookup to build a matrix for a dashboard view of test suite status (total tests, passed, failed, not run …..)

IT’s a very manual process. I’d like to use SSRS to generate the report, but I'm new to SSRS and I'm not sure how to structure the dataset to get the outcome of the tests. Does anyone one have and sample reports that pull test results into an excel like table?

Comment: Just check [Analyze and report on test results using the test perspective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/perspective-test-analyze-report-test-results?view=tfs-2018) and [Test Result tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/test-result-tables?view=tfs-2018), that should be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't have the Test perspective, we are using SQL Standard. What would the alternative be?

Comment: The goal would be to return what a pivot table would return so then I could use that as a dataset to populate a matrix.

Comment: It is difficult to achieve that, whatever you need to know about the data structure first, then try to customize your own report, refer to [How To: Customize a Report in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb668983(v=pandp.10)) for details. And also there is a [guide video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GL-xNlWRZSs) for your reference.

Comment: Is the data that is in the Test Perspective still available in SQL server standard? just not split out?